# Rails 3 mail with delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm continuing my migration from rails 2.3.12 to 3.0.9 and am now working sending email notifications through Gmail.

I followed the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) and I can now send emails properly in my rails 3.0 app when I do:

> Mailer.test_html(email).deliver

But I can't figure out how to send them as a background task. In my rails 2.3 app, I used to use the delayed_job_mailer plugin to send emails as a background task. I now deleted the plugin. I also installed a newer version of the delayed_job gem (2.1.4). But, the

> ```
> Mailer.delay.test_html(email)
> ```

command doesn't send the email on my development machine. In the logs, I can see the matching task being inserted in the delayed_jobs table. But I don't know when the task is being treated and deleted from the delayed_jobs table... and I don't receive any email.

In my development.rb file, I have:

> config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
>   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

but I'm not even sure if this is really useful. Any idea about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the `rake jobs:work` task to have a process by Delayed Job work off jobs from that table. Without this, you will not receive any emails.

Comment: Thanks!!! Also, is it something I should include in my Capistrano recipe for my production environment?